# Replace coefficients with RootApproximant of themselves

Tags: replacement, algebraic-manipulation, coefficients

I have an expression, not necessarily a polynomial, and want to take all the coefficients on whatever terms there are and replace them with the `RootApproximant` versions of them. For example,

`a = 0.111803 z + 0.298142396`

I would like the result of my replacement to look like

`a = 1/(4 Sqrt[5]) z +  2/(3 Sqrt[5])`.

I have tried to use some conditional replacement rules, but I cannot figure out how to take the coefficient and use it in a function, then put it back in front of the symbolic part. I have tried this

`a /. t_ /; NumberQ[t] -> RootApproximant[t]`

But this doesn't understand what the final `t` in the `RootApproximant` is.

Comment: `a /. r_Real :> RootApproximant[r]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html), instead of a [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html), and so it's evaluating the RHS with the symbol `t` in as the argument of `RootApproximant`, which leads to the error message. Using `RuleDelayed` fixes it:

```
a /. t_ /; NumberQ[t] :> RootApproximant[t]
(* z*Root[1-10*#1+10*#1^2+<<5>>-6*#1^9+3*#1^10&,1,0] + ... *)
```

Comment: Thank you! That has indeed solved the issue